# $* and $@ in Bash Script

Tags: bash, parameters, arguments

What is the difference between $* and $@ in bash?

From the Bash doc,

[image]

The above description makes my brain hurt.
So I tried to figure out the difference with the following script ("myscript"):

```
echo $*
echo $@
```

If I run "myscript -x ARG1", the output is

```
-x ARG1
-x ARG1
```

That is, both produce the same output.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Almost always, the correct answer is: `"$@"` (don't forget the double-quotes). All other versions, with `$*` or without the double-quotes, lead to weird parsing of one sort or another. *Understanding* the weird parsing is not necessary, just remember: `"$@"`. Also, don't try to assign a list of arguments to a plain variable, like `args="$@"`, because that also causes confusion.

Comment: Both lines in `myscript` are bad.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find out what is wrong and how to fix it.  Very many shell code problems can be found that way.